Value Assignment and Checking for Subscripted Variables
I'm using a subscript as a counter in some code. Here, I give a value:
Subscript[θ, 1] = 0

Without making any other assignments, I want to check if other Subscript[θ, i]  have values.
Table[Subscript[θ, i], {i, 3}]
Table[ValueQ[Subscript[θ, i]], {i, 3}]

This give {0, Subscript[θ, 2], Subscript[θ, 3]} and {True,True,True}. Why isn't the second output {True,False,False}?

It's because Subscript[θ, i] evaluates to Subscript[θ, 2] and so it has a value. If you were to use Table[With[{i = i}, ValueQ[Subscript[θ, i]]], {i, 3}] you would get your desired result.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Use indexed variables displayed as subscripted variables.
Format[θ[i_]] := Subscript[θ, i]

θ[1] = 0;

Table[θ[i], {i, 3}]

(* {0, Subscript[θ, 2], Subscript[θ, 3]} *)

If a value has been assigned then the Head is not θ
Table[Head[θ[i]] =!= θ, {i, 3}]

(* {True, False, False} *)

Or, to test for a numeric value
Table[NumericQ[θ[i]], {i, 3}]

(* {True, False, False} *)


NumericQ does it. I was hoping that the documentation on ValueQ would contain something like this in the See Also menu, but crickets.
